# How to have a "WHERE"/"LIKE"/CONCAT combined with count and group by in sql?

Tags: php, sql, count, concatenation

Just managed this one as I wanted it to work (had to translate, but I hope it is correct);

```sql
SELECT birthyear, agentid, count(agentid) AS agentcount, agent.fname, agent.lname, agent.id AS agentid 
FROM company 
INNER JOIN agent ON agent.id=company.agentid 
GROUP BY company
```

But how do I, to use this with a search bar add that i want this `WHERE x LIKE '%%%s%%'` to specify who I want to get when I search after a name? Just get "not functionally dependent on columns in group by". Would like x to be fname+lname, tried concat but didn't really manage to test it as nothing really worked with any `WHERE`.

I have a separate $sql2 that takes out info like that (`WHERE x LIKE '%%%s%%'`) when I search on the website and will try to use both when searching, the $sql2 works, but I tried to make this with count but I don't know how, tried to search and add it different places, but cannot seem to understand.

Thank you

Comment: Your `GROUP BY` and `SELECT` clauses are inconsistent.  The query should b generating a syntax error.

Comment: Please don't post code as a single line.  Learning how to format code with consistent indents, etc, is one of the first steps to debugging your own code.

Comment: It makes no sense to select details of a specific agent like their name if you're counting all the agents in each company.

Comment: Isn't the code four lines?  Should I just have count alone in one and collect information through the other? But how do I, when everything else is OK, add WHERE fname+lname = '%%%s%%'?